# rsync SSD migration: lsetxattr failed: Operation not supported (95) -- consequences?

Tags: linux, ssd, rsync

I just got an SSD and have been trying to migrate to it, poring through tons of how-to's I finally decided on this command (I have multiple partitions that needed migrating):

```
time rsync -avHAXx /mntpnt/ /media/_mntpnt-ssd/ --exclude={"lost+found"} 2>rsync_errors-mntpnt-ssd
```

So I check the `rsync_errors-mntpnt-ssd` file, and it is full of messages that say:

> lsetxattr(""/media/_mntpnt-ssd/some/file"","security.selinux") failed: Operation not supported (95)

My original partitions are all mounted with these options reported by `mount`:

```
 /dev/sdaX on /mntpnt type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

except for one which is:

```
 /dev/sdaX on /mntpntX type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered)
```

The SSD partitions are mounted like this:

```
/dev/sdcX on /media/_mntpnt-ssd type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks)
```

automatically by clicking on the konqueror sidebar (in case that is relevant). I did however try remounting

```
mount -o remount,acl,user_xattr /dev/sdcX
```

But that didn't seem to change the options reported by `mount` nor did it prevent the error messages after trying the rsync again.

So my question is, can I safely ignore these warnings? Is the data that rsync could not copy (ie, the xattr) important? I think they are all selinux related (which I don't have enabled), but I haven't really searched through the logs to see if there are others. Can I just go ahead and do the switch and start booting from the SSD?

---

In case it is useful,

Current root partition:

```
#  tune2fs -l /dev/sdaX |grep ext_attr 
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
```

SSD partitions:

```
#  tune2fs -l /dev/sdcX |grep ext_attr 
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
```

But when mounting with:

```
umount /dev/sdcX && mount -o rw,acl,user_xattr -t ext4 /dev/sdcX /media/_mntpnt-ssd
```

no errors are reported, but mount says it is mounted as:

```
/dev/sdcX on /media/_mntpnt-ssd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Ie, no '`acl,user_xattr`', and using 'defaults,acl,user_xattr' in the mount command is no improvement either.

Comment: You want mount the target disks yourself. Otherwise, this won't work. `nosuid` and `nodev` are no good.

Comment: @DanielB, should unmount, then mount again, or is using `-o remount` good enough?

Comment: Do you want to clone the entire disk? If so you could take a look at the ```dd``` utility.

Comment: You need to stop `udisks` from interfering, so you’ll need to unmount completely and then mount again yourself (as `root`). `rsync` has to run as `root`, too, of course.

Comment: @Yamakaja I needed to resize the partitions, so `dd` was not a viable option.

Comment: @DanielB Ok, I will try that, and yeah, I was running `rsync` as root.

Comment: @DanielB Also, I updated the question to add more info.

Comment: Specifying mount options that are already set elsewhere (check the complete `tune2fs` output) is redundant. They won't be listed.

Comment: @DanielB ah ok, good to know. In any case, I am still getting the errors. Ie: `rsync: rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr(""/media/_mntpnt/somefile"","security.selinux") failed: Operation not supported (95)` I don't know what to do, and no amount of googling is yielding an answer